# Moving a pre-made OpenCV installation to another Linux computer

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I installed OpenCV for C++ on Linux by using this [guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

And then made it work with Eclipse with this [guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html).

However, I need to be able to use OpenCV for a few different Linux computers and this is where I have an issue.

The installation worked fine but it took a lot of time to make the file (over 3 hours) and therefore I would like to skip the installation when moving OpenCV to another Linux computer. I tried to copy over the pre-made OpenCV directory from my first installation to another computer, but when trying to find the OpenCV installation with this commando from the guide:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

I get this error message:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

I just want to make sure before I spend a half a day making OpenCV installations on every computer, is there a way to copy a pre-made OpenCV installation to another computer? It would save me a ton of time. Or do I simply need to follow the installation guide for each and every computer I want to use OpenCV on?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the parts of OpenCV have to be compiled for the specific processor.
This means you have to install compile them on the specific machine.
I'm assuming `cmake` is taking the majority of the time. To enhance this process
you can add an option -j followed by the number of threads the machine has.
For example `-j4` for a machine with 4 threads or `-j8` for a machine with 8 threads.
If you don't know how many threads your machine has you can use the command `lscpu` to get information about the CPU.

Comment: Okay, I thought it could have been like that. Well, I guess I just have to compile it for every computer. Thanks for the -j4 command, should save me some time!

Comment: If second host be like first host, it's possible to cmake & make & make install in first host and  make install in second host?